# sudo -l for a different as root

Tags: command, sudo, sudoers

Hi all am trying list all the sudo command a user has access to as a root , obviously we can see that in sudoers file but if there are a lot of user/command aliases it becomes difficult

i am trying to do sudo -l for a different user as root

i have tried using -u option

```
sudo -u testuser -l
```

throws command usage message

```
sudo -u testuser sudo -l
```

prompts for testuser's password (i dont want password prompt as i am doing as root)

```
su - testuser -c 'sudo -l'
```

gives me below error

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

please let me know how to go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `man sudo`:

```
 -U user, --other-user=user
             Used in conjunction with the -l option to list the privileges
             for user instead of for the invoking user.  The security pol-
             icy may restrict listing other users' privileges.  The
             sudoers policy only allows root or a user with the ALL privi-
             lege on the current host to use this option.
```

you're using `-u`, which is something completely different:

```
 -u user, --user=user
             Run the command as a user other than the default target user
             (usually root ). The user may be either a user name or a
             numeric user ID (UID) prefixed with the '#' character etc...
```

Comment: The man page still says that using `-l` in conjunction with `-u user` should work, so that still seems like a bug.  `-U` reads like it's testing for what can be done if invoked by a different user, while `-u` is for running a command as a user other than root.  Querying "what commands can I can if I, the same current invoking user, were to sudo to a non-root UID" is a different situation and doesn't seem to be supported.